# Reclass to decimals

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, reclassify

I have a integer raster with values 1 - 10, I would like to reclass each value to a decimal e.g 0.003, 0.44 etc. This obviously doesnt work in the Reclass tool, as only whole numbers are allowed. Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiply everything by orders of magnitude until you are working with integers rather than decimals.

In other words, if your raster has values of 1-10, and you want to reclassify some of those values to 0.003, multiply your integer raster by 1000 so that its values range between 1000 and 10000. Then instead of reclassifying to 0.003, reclassify to 3. After reclassification, you can divide the values in your reclassified raster by 1000 to get the original decimal values you wanted.